# Scala How to transform Seq[((A, B, C, D), Seq[(E, F, G)])] to Seq[(A, B, C, D, Seq[(E, F, G)])]?

Tags: scala, sequence

I'd like to transform the following sequence.

```
Seq[((A, B, C, D), Seq[(E, F, G)])]
```

to

```
Seq[(A, B, C, D, Seq[(E, F, G)])]
```

Could anyone kindly suggest a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simply:

```
val original: Seq[((A, B, C, D), Seq[(E, F, G)])] = ...
val res: Seq[(A, B, C, D, Seq[(E, F, G)])] =
  original.map { case ((a, b, c, d), seq) => (a, b, c, d, seq) }
```